# NaHCO3 decomposition dynamics and extent vs Temperature

Tags: aqueous-solution, solubility, gas-laws

I'm wondering approximately how fast and to which extent $\ce{NaHCO3}$ will decompose (to $\ce{CO2}$ and $\ce{H2O}$) at $50$, $60$, $70$, $80$, $90$, $100$, $110$, $120$, and $\pu{130 ^\circ C}$.

It seems as if [*J. Environ. Sci.* **2019,** *78,* 74–80](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jes.2018.07.005) would answer my question but unfortunately I can't access the content.

Does anyone know ?

Comment: If you notice it says "thermodynamics" and not "kinetics" . kinetics decides the speed whereas thermodynamics discusses the feasibilty.

Comment: Safdar, you are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper doesn't tell how fast will it be.

As for the rest, have this:

[image: decomp-solution]

[image: decomp-solid]

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer to the actual answer more a comment with images. Wouldn't it be better to link it to an answer in [the sandbox](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4755/formatting-sandbox-iii-please-test-stuff-here)?

Comment: True, but you can't include images in comments, and using the sandbox to this end seems somehow far-fetched.